# Google play services auth -- trouble getting a project to build

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

project level build.gradle file:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.0'
        classpath 'com.google.protobuf:protobuf-gradle-plugin:0.8.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
   }
}
[...]
```

Application-level build.gradle (much abridged, due to large numbers of irrelevant dependencies here):

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.3"
}

ext {
    supportLibraryVersion = '24.2.1'
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:${supportLibraryVersion}"
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:9.8.0'
}
```

Gives me the following build errors:

> google-services plugin could not detect any version for
>   com.google.android.gms or com.google.firebase, default version: 9.0.0
>   will be used. please apply google-services plugin at the bottom of the
>   build file.
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong: A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
>
>   > Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:_debugApkCopy'.
>   >     Could not find com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:9.8.0.
>   >      Required by:
>   >          SpeechDemo:app:unspecified

I tried moving the "apply plugin" line for google-services to the very bottom line of the file, but other than removing the warning about it this changed nothing.

Any ideas how to make this work?

Comment: Do you have the Android Support Repository downloaded?

Comment: Disagree with the marking of this as a duplicate.  The error message is not the same, and the accepted answer specifies a change that I have already tried and which has not resolved the issue (a fact which is noted in the question description).

Comment: @AdamGardner - Yes, although it turned out that the copy I have (installed less than a month ago) is too old to work with the documentation up on the web site any more.